# Extend the api of packaged apps?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im experimenting with packaged apps for chrome at the time.

I wonder if it is planned that I can extend the chrome packaged app with my own set of APIs, via C++ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call C and C++ code from Chrome Packaged Apps using [NaCl](https://developers.google.com/native-client/), with some limitations. However, you cannot add to or change the chrome.* namespace, specifically.